# How to get more info on AnimationException?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, exception, try-catch

I have a WPF application where I create a `Storyboard` to animate some controls. After triggering the animation the project breaks but all I get from Visual Studio is the bellow output message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationException' in WindowsBase.dll
```

How is it possible to get more info so I would know exactly where the problem is? The documentation only states that

> The exception that is thrown when an error occurs while animating a
>   property.

I have no idea in which line the code broke in order to insert a `try-catch` block.

Comment: You create an animation in a storyboard. That is an object which you then start. Unless you wrote a custom animation, there won't be a line in your code to return an error. What animation are you using on what?

Comment: Ineed I wrote a custom animation @Andy. The storyboard includes `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` and `DoubleAnimation`. I apply it to normal controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would catch these unhandled exceptions like this:

```
public MyCustomControl()
{
  Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
}

void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Exception)
  {
    case AnimationException aniEx:
      Log(aniEx.GetDetails());
      break;
    // ...
    // default: ...
  }
}
```

and second I would add a GetDetails extension for exceptions to get all details out of it:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all Details of an exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetDetails(this Exception exception)
    {
        string GetInnerExceptionDetails(Exception e)
        {
            var s = new StringBuilder(e.GetType().FullName);
            if (e.GetType().GetProperties()
                 .Select(prop => new { prop.Name, Value = prop.GetValue(e, null) })
                 .Select(x => $"{x.Name}: {x.Value ?? string.Empty}").ToList() is List<string> props && props.Any())
            {
                s.AppendLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, props));
                s.AppendLine();
            }

            if (e.InnerException != null)
                s.AppendLine(GetInnerExceptionDetails(e.InnerException));
            return s.ToString();
        }
        return GetInnerExceptionDetails(exception);
    }
}
```